# If $\mu$ is a signed measure, does $\mu(E)=0$ and $F \subset E$ imply $\mu(F)=0$?

Tags: measure-theory

> Let $(X, \mathcal{A})$ be a measurable space and let $\mu$ be a signed measure on $\mathcal{A}$. Let $E, F \in  \mathcal{A}$, $F \subset E$. Does $\mu(E)=0$ imply $\mu(F)=0$?

I couldn't find any counterexample - the examples of signed measures that I know do satisfy this.

Comment: What would be some examples of signed measures that (you) know (which) satisfy this? I have trouble finding even one...

Comment: I lied to make you believe I had thought about the problem.

Comment: "I lied to make you believe I had thought about the problem." T'is at least good that you admit it.

Comment: I'm sorry :( ...

Comment: That's really funny.  I'm laughing so hard now!

Comment: "I'm sorry." Are you (sorry), or are you *lying to make us believe that* you are (sorry)? If you are (sorry), can you explain what you are (sorry) about?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take $f(x)= \chi_{[-1,1]}(x) \cdot x $, and consider the measure $d\mu =f dm$ where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on the real line. This means that
$$\mu(E) = \int_{E} fdm$$
for measureable sets $E$. Then $\mu(\mathbb R)= 0$, but $\mu(0,\infty)\neq 0$.

Answer (score 2):

No. E.g. let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be two measure spaces each with a usual (i.e. non-negative) measure, say $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$, so that $\mu_i(X_i) = 1$.  Now let
$X = X_1 \coprod X_2$ (disjoint union), and define the measure $\mu$ on $X$ to be
$\mu_1$ on $X_1$ and $-\mu_2$ on $X_2$.  Then $\mu(X) = \mu(X_1) + \mu(X_2) = 1 - 1 = 0,$ but neither $X_1$ nor $X_2$ has measure zero.

Answer (score 2):

On $\mathbb R$, define
$$
\mu(A)=m(A\cap[0,\infty))-m(A\cap(-\infty)).
$$
This is by definition a signed measure. And you have $\mu([-1,1])=0$, $\mu([0,1])=1$.